# Show that $\nabla m_t$ is a polynomial o degree $p-1$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, proof-verification, self-learning, time-series

> If $m_t=\sum_{k=0}^p c_kt^k$ $t=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots$ show that $\nabla
>  m_t$ is a polynomial o degree $p-1$ int $t$ and hence that
>   $\nabla^{p+1} m_t=0$

EDIT: I made a mistake $\nabla$ is not a gradient operator, it is a difference operator, such that $\nabla x_t=x_t-x_{
t-1}$

$$\nabla m_t=\sum_{k=0}^p c_kt^k-\sum_{k=0}^p c_k(t-1)^k$$

$$=c_pt^p+\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}c_kt^k-c_p(t-1)^p-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}c_k(t-1)^k$$

$$=c_pt^p-c_p(t-1)^p+\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}c_kt^k-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}c_k(t-1)^k$$

$$=c_p(t^p-(t-1)^p)+\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}c_kt^k-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}c_k(t-1)^k$$

What I know is that when I expand $(t-1)^p$, it will give a coefficient $t^p$ that will cancel with other $t^p$ then the order of polynomial will be $p-1$, but I do not know how to develop it formally.

The answer just say

> $$\nabla m_t=pc_pt^{p-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{p-2}b_kt^k$$

Comment: If $m_t$ is an arbitrary function, this is clearly wrong. For example, suppose $m_t$ has these values for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and thus also for all integer $t$. Set $\tilde m_t = m_t + \sin \pi t$. Then $\tilde m_t$ has the same values for all integer $t$, but $\nabla m_t$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the question.  It is highly unlikely that $\nabla$ is being used to mean "gradient" here, especially as $m_t$ is a function of only *one* integer variable (there's no vector of derivatives as you claim).  It would be far more reasonable for $\nabla$ to be a finite differencing operator, either forward or backward.

Comment: The expansion of $(t-1)^p$ can be written formally with the binomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)

$$(x+y)^n = \sum _{k=1} ^n \binom n k x^n y^{n-k} ,$$

we may write

$$\nabla m_t = m_t - m_{t-1} = \sum _{k=0} ^p c_k t^k - \sum _{k=0} ^p c_k \color{blue} {(t-1)^k} = \sum _{k=0} ^p c_k t^k - \sum _{k=0} ^p c_k \color{blue} {\sum _{i=0} ^k \binom k i t^i (-1)^{k-i}} = \\
\text{[split the last sum]} = \underbrace{ \sum _{k=0} ^p c_k t^k - \sum _{k=0} ^p c_k \underbrace{ \binom k k t^k (-1)^{k-k} }_{= t^k}} _{= 0} - \sum _{k= \color{red} 1} ^p c_k \sum _{i=0} ^{\color{red} {k-1}} \binom k i t^i (-1)^{k-i} = \\
\text{[let } l = k-1 \text{]} = - \sum _{l=0} ^{p-1} c_{l+1} \sum _{i=0} ^l \binom {l+1} i t^i (-1)^{l+1-i} = \\
\text{[interchange the sums]} = - \sum _{i=0} ^{p-1} t^i \sum _{l=i} ^{p-1} c_{l+1} \binom {l+1} i (-1)^{l+1-i} ,$$

and letting

$$\tilde c_i = - \sum _{l=i} ^{p-1} c_{l+1} \binom {l+1} i (-1)^{l+1-i}$$

allows us to finally write

$$\nabla m_t = \sum _{i=0} ^{p-1} \tilde c_i t^i ,$$

showing that, indeed, $\nabla m_t$ is a polynomial of degree *at most* $p-1$.

Notice that if $m_t$ is a polynomial of degree *exactly* $p$, then $c_p \ne 0$. On the other hand,

$$\tilde c _{p-1} = - \sum _{l = p-1} ^{p-1} c_{l+1} \binom {l+1} {p-1} (-1)^{l+1-(p-1)} = - c_p \binom p {p-1} (-1)^1 = p c_p ,$$

so if $c_p \ne 0$, it follows that $\tilde c _{p-1} \ne 0$, so $\nabla m_t$ has degree *exactly* $p-1$.

It is easy to reason recursively, now, in order to deduce that $\nabla ^2 m_t$ is a polynomial of order $p-2$, and, in general, $\nabla ^k m_t$ is a polynomial of order $p-k$ for $0 \le k \le p$. In particular, $\nabla ^p m_t$ is a polynomial of order $p-p = 0$, so it is a constant, therefore $\nabla ^{p+1} m_t = 0$.